# Looking for a version control system that supports standard development and customer specific development

Tags: version-control

At our company we've built a data integration tool that we have sold to several customers. Most of the customers have distinct requirements. We implemented these **customer-specific extensions** by using a self-made mechanism based on inheritance (so every installation knows which classes to load and which not). But all this customer-specific code is still **in the same codebase** as the standard code.

Now, this is no longer possible for several reasons (codebase getting ugly and large, clashing requirements, etc.)

For this reason we have decided to **separate the codebases**: one for the standard product, and several customer-specific codebases.

I am now trying to find a version control system that supports this approach. Here's my wishlist:

- support for several "standard" codebases for different releases

  - 1.0 release
  - 1.1 release
  - 2.0 beta/development
- support for multiple "customer" codebases
- ability to create a customer codebase by cloning a standard codebase
- ability to change standard code in a customer codebase
- ability to update a customer codebase with a new standard release (and somehow marking the conflicts that come from changed standard code in the customer codebase)

As our team is still very small (~4 programmers), it should also be easy to handle by the developers themselves.

Btw, our software is built using [Spring](http://www.spring.io) with [STS](http://spring.io/tools/sts) (so, an Eclipse plugin would be great too).

All VCS that I have researched so far seem to have that target of building *one* piece of software - not several. I am hoping for some suggestions or best-practice approches.

Comment: Aren't you just looking for *branching* which is a facility provided by every vc system I've worked with in the last 20 years ?

Comment: I've also asked that to myself - do I have the *upgrade* possibility too with "plain old" branches? (Make branch A, add some extra stuff there, then ship everything from the main branch to branch A but keep the extra stuff?)

Comment: Nothing you've told us makes me think that branching, using your current VCS, isn't a good (enough) solution for your current problems.  Sure, you have to do a little thinking and work up front to tailor your approach to your tool (and/or your tool to your approach) and make sure everyone understands the new requirements. If you don't already have a VCS then (a) naughty, naughty you, and (b) get Subversion.  Personally, I wouldn't touch a distributed VCS with a bargepole.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark : now I know, what barge pole is. Funny. You, as presumably long term SVN power user encourage others to use VCS, otherwise they are naughty - I agree. I encourage you to try some distributed VCS. There are advantages (easy cloning, merging, having complete history when yo do not have access to the server), which one can appreciate - but it requires touching it by hands. It seems, that being long term power user of SVN or CVS is sort of barrier for adopting distributed VCS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Simply

Simply get git, go for pull request process and take advantage of some GUI, supporting this workflow.

## Are releases much different form custom development?

To clarify, what is the situation you are facing: "standard" development comes in versions, they might live independent for maintenance, you may need to get some fixes from new versions to be incorporated in older releases, you need a way to solve hotfixes.

All these things are well solved by distributed version control systems like git, hg or others. I have started with hg, but later found, git is used more often and in standard installation offers all what is need (what is not a case for some hg features).

Regarding custom development - in fact, they do not differ conceptually much from standard versions - you just need another modification of your program being identified under unique name, which will eventually denote, these are custom things.

## Branching or pull request process?

Now how to approach different "swim-lines" for different versions and custom developments?

### Branching workflow models

Obvious answer is "branching". There is a lot of tutorials on various branching models and they shall be solving your problem.

However, branching is not trivial either and you may find long disputes on what style is the best one.

### Topical repos and pull request workflow

Fortunately, there are even simpler solutions - Pieter Hintjens article http://hintjens.com/blog:24 about "Branching considered harmful" provides simpler model, using topical repositories and pull request process. This is how many projects on GitHub and BitBucket are managed and I found this really the most effective solution with minimal risks.

## Final recommendations

For pull request working process, it is handy to have some GUI, which supports related communication - and apart form GitHub and BitBucket, there are solutions on the market (incl. some open source solutions).

Prepare yourself for long run - starting with linked article by Pieter Hintjens may make your run a bit shorter, next step could be playing with a project on BitBucket or so, then design "the final" system (which will anyway evolve during time, but git repos are well suited to keep with the changes).

Comment: thanks for the introductiona and the links. We are currently using mercurial, and I will have a deeper look into "named branches".

Comment: We've now come up to the following solution with different branches: **default** (standard development branch), **revision1.0** (standard development branch for bugfixing), **revision1.1** (standard development branch for bugfixing), **customerA** (a clone from "revision1.0" with some changes). We now looking into how we can restrict the way changes are made between these branches, but I'll post a different question on that.

Comment: [Here is the followup question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401594/restrict-the-content-of-pushs-to-avoid-accidental-pushes-to-the-development-bra)

Comment: +1 for creating follow up question. You seem to know, what you are doing and did not fall into [chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) trap.